# Windows (or Linux) program for light and value

Tags: software-recommendation, windows, linux

Is there a program for Windows (or Linux if all else fails) for studying light and value? For example, I would like to study geometric solids being exposed to different types of light from different angles, in grayscale & color. Are there any stand-alone programs that can do that or maybe an Adobe or Corel plugin?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? It sounds like some 3D rendering.. The colors of real objects depend on the material (chemical structure). Geometric objects don't have any color by default.

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, coyote.foxtrot. As @Ivan Kuckir pointed, you should be more explicit regarding the scope of your study. Do you need different versions of the same object changing the conditions of the light (give a look at [POV-Ray](http://www.povray.org) or [Blender](https://www.blender.org))? Do you need just a bunch of decorative objects (give a look at [Paint 3D](https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/help/4014937/windows-10-get-to-know-the-paint-3d-tools))? Do you need to analyze existing images (get a try to [ImageJ](https://imagej.nih.gov/ij))? Tell us something more, please.